# Datos comunes en dos dataframe en r

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Hola tengo una consulta básica de lenguaje r que no he encontrado solución en el archivo de preguntas:

Tengo dos dataframes con datos biológicos, en la primera columna de dos dataframes tengo nombres de moléculas, es de mi interés saber que moléculas están presentes o son comunes en ambos dataframes.

He probado sin éxito lo siguiente:
`which (list1 %in% list2)`
y

`x <- as.integer(list1 %in% list2)`

He logrado obtener respuesta con el siguiente codigo

`comunes <- as.matrix (ifelse(is.na(match(SigGenes_CCR$X1, SigGenes_Prostate$X1)),"no","yes"))`

Quisiera obtener el nombre de la molecula coincidente y no el indice.

Gracias por sus orientaciones!

Comment: ¿Que es list1 y list2? ¿puedes agregar la salida de `str(List1)`?

Comment: Patricio son los dataframe con mis datos

Comment: Ok, entonces necesitamos conocer la estructura de las mismas, te repito, podrías agregar a tu pregunta la estructura con `str(list1)`?

Comment: ```tabla1 <- data.frame(X1 = c("CCN", "P53", "MGB1", "HB6","PY3"))
tabla2 <- data.frame(X1= c("CCN", "CIK", "POL3", "P53"))```

Comment: Este es un símil ya que tengo miles de datos

Comment: A ver, intenta esto: `SigGenes_CCR$X1[SigGenes_CCR$X1 %in% SigGenes_Prostate$X1]`

Comment: Gracias Patricio, me ha funcionado tu recomendación, una consulta adicional, si tengo varios ```data.frame``` para realizar el mismo ejercicio de buscar datos en común entre ellos, tienes alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo?

Comment: Primero que nada cargar cada `data.frame` en un  listaA y los otros en una  ListaB, luego simplemente un ciclo para recorrer de a uno los elementos de las listas y hacer la búsqueda de elementos compartidos

Comment: Buscando solución a mi problema, he creado una lista de mis 7 `Data.frame` para intentar de una manera automática encontrar el intercepto de los 7 `Data.frame`, he creado el siguiente bucle: `Project <- list ( df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7) for(i in 1:length(project)){
  for(j in 2:length(project)){
  uniontemp <- merge(project[i], project[j], by="row.names")
  final <- list(uniontemp)
  }
}` Pero no me funciona, solo logra comparar el df1 con todos y el df2 con todos pero no avanzo de este punto, agradezco me orienten en una solución, gracias